# Search line in Chrome Developer Toolbar has disappeared after updating Chrome. How to get it back?

Tags: google-chrome, web-developer-toolbar

In Chrome there is a search line in its console. Here's the picture of it from [google.dev.com page](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console):

[image]

And here is my console. No any search line now:

[image]

Did anybody encounter such a problem? How can I get it back?

Comment: What version of Chrome is this? I'm in v20 and it's in there.

Comment: @Arran, version 22.0.1229.79 m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and it will re-appear on the bottom.

Comment: Thank you vary much. Is this the way they decided to update the searchline for good now? Or they will bring back the previous one later?

Answer (score 1):

Press  "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "F" and then F12, search results will show up.
Quite annoying.